# Centering a button in an iframe

Tags: html, css, button

[image]

Quick question here on a button that is inside an iframe. I'm attaching a screenshot to make it clear, but basically, the orange button at the bottom of this iframe for some reason does not center. I'm playing around in developer tools and I've noticed that there is a table data that seems to be in the way, but I can't figure out how to adjust it. Maybe you guys can help me with this one!

You can see the iframe here: https://sandrelle.ie/book-online/

Comment: What can we do without code ?

Comment: As Arthur says, we need a [MCVE] to help here, as I assume the low hanging fruit has already been tried. On several occasions, I have found that creating that example actually lead me to the answer before I had posted my question.

Comment: jaysus, sorry guys, forgot to add the link, I edited my post with the link where you can see the iframe embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Add text-align:center to your containing button div

Answer (score 0):

so it turns out I was able to fix it myself. The issue originally was that it was formatted in a way that table data was getting in the way and pushing the button to the side, so I had just deleted the extra td that was in there.